# Hibernate Exception: detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am looking couple of linke here and doc, still not figureout the problem.
I am migrating Spring 4.2 and Hibernate 4.3.x. I am facing a basic proble while persisting Object.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER_TYPE")
public class CustomerType implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Column(name = "CID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int custTypeId;

@Column(name = "C_TYPE_NAME", nullable = false)
private String custTypeName;

@Column(name = "C_TYPE_CODE", nullable = false)
private String custTypeCode;

// setters and gettes

}
```

Service class :

```
@Service("customerTypeService")
@Transactional
public class CustomerTypeServiceImpl implements CustomerTypeService {

@Autowired
private CustomerTypeDao customerTypeDao;
  // business methods and dao access point
}
```

my Abstract Dao is:

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<PK extends Serializable, T> {
   public void persist(T entity) {
 // getSession().persist(entity.getClass().getName(), entity);
    getSession().persist(entity);
//  getSession().flush();
}

}
```

Test class from where I am passing test data:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
    ctx.refresh();
    ctx.start();
    CustomerTypeService cust = ctx.getBean(CustomerTypeService.class);

    CustomerType customerType = new CustomerType();
    customerType.setCustTypeCode("D");
    //customerType.setCustTypeId(4);
    customerType.setCustTypeName("DOCTOR");

    cust.saveCustomerType(customerType);
```

And

```
Exception is: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.myproject.springmvc.model.CustomerType.
```

**EDIT**
Tx Manager in Config class:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
   HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
   txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
   return txManager;
}
```

Comment: did you add <tx:annotation-driven/> in the xml?

Comment: I am not following xml based approch, I decided to go with Configuration class,

Comment: pretty sure you have it. where is the datasource you have attached to your config class. If not there then where is your EntityManager? how do you initialize your hibernate? dont you have something like:   AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
    config.addAnnotatedClass(CustomerType.class);
    config.configure();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();